# Please Wait iPhone - No NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am currently using `NSTimer` to load a "Please Wait" alert view in my application while it contacts a server. I want to get rid of this `NSTimer` and change it so that it runs the "Please Wait" alert view in a loop until it gets a response from the server.

How would I do this?

Comment: Showing that *alert* there is definitely a bad user experience. Do consider reading the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Introduction/Introduction.html). It will help you design better user experiences.

Comment: I'll go through this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A loop would be bad (blocking the main thread), but if you use [`NSURLConnection`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) object you get a `connectionDidFinishLoading:` message in the delegate.

- You pop up the alert when you start the connection.
- You dismiss the alert in the `connectionDidFinishLoading:` of your delegate.

  - And also when an error occurs.

---

Though I agree with @Radu when it's about user experience.

Comment: This wouldn't be the problem. He would show an UIAlertView (with no buttons?) which blocks the UI.

Comment: @mavrick3 It would already hang the alert itself when it tries to animate in place unless a timer is used. And Jamas doesn't want to use a timer, he said.

Comment: @WTP Oh.. I didn't understand the question correctly, but I would suggest like you NSURLConnection +1

Answer (score 2):

Set up a [delegate for the NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDelegate). Your delegate will then receive messages at interesting points in the connection, such as when data is received and when the connection is finished.

Answer (score 0):

try [this page](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/09/managing-the-network-activity-indicator/). It helps manage cases where there might be more than one network event going on.